# Handling Null Logically

Tags: c#, .net

Here, the line `return session.Dictionary.ContainsKey(SessionId)` must be able to return the values of both true and false. I am aware the `if` statement I am using in this example requires all code paths to return a value, and this is problematic for the function I created to deal with cases where the `SessionId` is a `null` string as if I return a value of `true` or `false` it may interfere with the code and and allow the `null` value through. Are there any better way to handle exceptions or a way that this approach could work?

```
private bool sessionExists(string SessionId)
{
   if(!nullExceptionHandler(SessionId)
   {
       return sessionDictionary.ContainsKey(SessionId);
   }
   else
   {
       return 
   }
```

Comment: Why would `SessionId` be null? Stop that from happening and you won't have to check for it every time you use it.

Comment: Rule of thumb is don't catch exceptions you can't (or don't know how to) handle.

Comment: This function will be used to receive HTML requests where I do not have direct control over the data the program is given.

Comment: I thin you must seperate responsibilities of this `SessionExists()` method. If there is no sessionId, you musn't check if exist or not.

Comment: if you play a game of football and the score is 0-0. Then suddenly ball is gone, does score change? so here. If session ID is null, then session does not exit. Because there is no session id with value = null

Answer (score 0):

From your code logic, you should return `false`, because if you don't accept a `null` `string` as a `Key`, testing whether it exists must be `false` :

```
if ( !nullExceptionHandler(SessionId) )
{ 
    return sessionDictionary.ContainsKey(SessionId);
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

So, in fact, you don't need such a method, you just need the `Add` method of your wrapper to the collection to not accept `null`.

In addition to that, the unknown `nullExceptionHandler` seems to be useless.

Also, a dictionnary does not accept `null` as a `Key`.

Perhaps you want to disallow `string.Empty` as a `Key`.

Therefore you can write such thing:

```
public class Sessions
{

  private readonly Dictionary<string, int> Items
    = new Dictionary<string, int>();

  public int Count => Items.Count;

  public bool Exists(string sessionId)
  {
    return Items.ContainsKey(sessionId);
  }

  public void Add(string sessionId, int value)
  {
    if ( sessionId == null )
      throw new System.ArgumentException($"{nameof(sessionId)} = (null)");
    if ( sessionId == string.Empty )
      throw new System.ArgumentException($"{nameof(sessionId)} = \"\"");
    Items.Add(sessionId, value);
  }

  public void Remove(string sessionId)
  {
    if ( Items.ContainsKey(sessionId) )
      Items.Remove(sessionId);
  }

}
```

I put the members public to be applied to the classic composed-wrapper case, but if you only handle things internally in the class for a dedicated logic, since you are using private in your code, it is the same with a few variations.